# UIMenuController respond very slowly

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uimenucontroller

I'm working on epub reader , simply I built the reader structure to get the path of html file load it on `UIWebView` , then I paginate the chapter and view it ... as you know when you select a text in webView the menuController will appear and I have multiple features on it like add note , highlight text, share ..etc. every thing is working great , but i have a special case that some books contains big chapters (html file size about 180kb where the normal one usually is about 30-50kb) , in these kind of chapters when I select a text the `UIMenuController` take too much time to appear ! at the end it is appearing and working well but its annoying to the users to wait this amount of time (we are talking here about 7 seconds !!) .. my build target is iOS 4 & 5 , and this is happened in the simulator and device .. can anyone provide a help ?

**Edit:**

canPerformAction in my ViewController  :

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    BOOL can = [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];

    if(action == @selector(copyPressed::) || 
       action == @selector(addNotePressed:) || 
       action == @selector(sharePressed:) || 
       action == @selector(highlightPressed:))
    {
        can = YES;
    }

    if (action == @selector(copy:) || action == @selector(_define:) || action == @selector(selectAll:) || action == @selector(select:)) 
    {
        can =  NO;
    }

    return can;
}
```

Comment: It is most likely being caused by the "canPerformAction" function.  What does yours look like?

Comment: Alright, it's not there...my next guess is that you are loading all of the html into one long stream and the menu controller has to think hard about where to put the popover.  You can confirm which function is taking a long time by using the Time Profiler function of Instruments.  After you do that, you will have a better idea of what is taking so long.  Until then, it is hard to say what is causing it.

Comment: Did u find out which function taking the long time using the Time Profiler?

Comment: Yes its the canPerformAction , and its code in my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working on an identical project and have just implemented the same functions with UIMenuController . I haven't noticed any delays showing the menu with large chapters. Could you describe the way your touch events are being handled in UIWebView along with any additional gestures etc. Also, is there javascript that's being run when the chapter loads?

Comment: Ok .. its really complicated to describe it all here but i try to describe it in simple way .. I receive the touch through the hitTest method from my webView Class.. I know its wrong to subclass the webView but there is nothing inside this class except the hitTest method .. I did it like that because i need to know exactly where is the touch point in some cases like if he press on highlighted text , I receive an url from javaScript that he press on highlight so i present the pop menu if he want to remove or share this text, I have no delay in these cases at all .. its just the normal selection

Comment: on the big chapters as I describe.

Comment: I too subclass UIWebView, but implement canPerformAction in the subclass and then extend the UIWebView delegate to pass on the menu selections to the UIViewController which owns the view.As a sanity check, does changing the 'animated' option in UIMenuController setMenuVisible affect the performance? How are you building and showing the menu? Myself, I pre-build all the menu options and then choose what to show in canPerformAction using my own menu state.

Comment: so you are forward the menu action from the webView subclass to the viewController ? actually i built it and perform the action inside the viewController .. if i did it on your way can i get better performance ?

Comment: can you please show me your custom webView class ? I think it will helpful to check your implementation .. and the bounty will expired soon i will award it to you In case i got any change in the performance.

Comment: actually I'm having a little better performance when I move the canPerformaction to my custom webView .. but I'm still interested to see your way in building the menu because it didn't solve the problem yet .. and in case you show a sub menu how you built it .. so Im gonna to award you the bounty because it will expired after few hours .. but don't forget that I'm waiting your replay .

Comment: Thanks :-) Here's how I build the menus : 1) In my ViewController class in viewDidAppear, I create all the possible UIMenuItem options menu options and call setMenuitems 2) in my subclassed UIWebView, I have a canPerformAction which uses a switch() depending on the mode i.e. first use, editing highlight colour, or editing highlight style (i.e. I have hierarchical menus). The menus are shown with a calls to  UIMenuController setTargetRect, setArrowDirection followed by setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES. The subclassed UIWebView manages the menu modes and defines a protocol for the menu actions.

Comment: Ok I decrease the time from 7 seconds to 2 seconds to make the menu appear .. you absolutely deserve the bounty .. Thanks man.